# Absolute position header not sticking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the header to hide while scrolling and to appear when stop scrolling at any point.

Normally I want it to appear as sticky header. It will actually be a sticky header which hides only while scrolling. While scrolling up and also while scrolling down.

Trying **.sticky {position: fixed;}** actually sticks it for always, but I want it to hide while scrolling. That is why I used position absloute.

[In the link it solves: while scrolling down header will hide and while scrolling up header will appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505795/hide-header-when-scroll-down-and-show-when-down)

Can anyone help me?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
}
.sticky {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>


</div>
```

Comment: Absolute is relative to its closest relatively positioned parent, but still a child of that parent, so will scroll off screen. Fixed or sticky is what you want, hiding on scroll needs to be achieved with javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide header when scroll down and show when down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505795/hide-header-when-scroll-down-and-show-when-down)

Comment: @pilchard that's not what I want moreover there is no original code there.

Comment: why you don't use `position:sticky`? the position fixed or sticky is the best way to do that, when you set the position absolute then the item should stay in it place, if a web page have a big hieght and you set `top:0%` for your item then when you scroll the item will stay in the top of your page and it won't be relative with scroll bar, but sticky should be relative, when you scroll the sticky item should be displaying in top of the page while your scrolling down,also if you want to add an animation or something else then use JS to change the color of the navbar or the width or anything else